# Importar Emails para um CRM

Tags: email

Gostaria de saber como fazer uma integração das mensagem enviadas via CRM em php, e quando a pessoa responder, conseguir importar o e-mail automaticamente para o CRM.

Eu imaginei algo da seguinte forma, habilitar o e-mail no servidor, pegatudo, e quando mandar uma mensagem pelo CRM, colocar no reply-to:id_do_registro@meudinio.com, habilitar o módulo de IMAP no php e ler o e-mail, baseado em seu Header para encontrar o TO

Será que dá certo?
Existe algum lugar que explique algo, vi isso no pipedrive
Marco

Answer (score 2):

Use as funções de [**IMAP**](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php) para obter as listas de mensagem e pode usar o filtro para detectar as mensagens que deseja

Então para conectar e obter os UIDs da INBOX use algo como se for com SSL:

```
$mbox = imap_open('{imap.dominio.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', '<seu email>', '<senha>');
```

Se **não** for com SSL:

```
$mbox = imap_open('{imap.dominio.com:143/imap/novalidate-cert}INBOX', '<seu email>', '<senha>');
```

E para buscar as mensagens crie uma variavel assim:

```
$filters = array();
```

E escolha os tipos de filtros, busca pelo conteudo do e-mail:

```
$corpo = '<busca algo no corpo da pergunta>';
$corpo = addcslashes($corpo, '"\\');

$filters[] = 'BODY "' . $corpo . '"';
$filters[] = 'TEXT "' . $corpo . '"';
```

Busca pelo remetente:

```
$remetente = '<endereço de quem enviou o email>';

$filters[] = 'FROM "' . addcslashes($remetente, '"\\') . '"';
```

Busca pelo assunto:

```
$assunto = '<assunto/titulo da mensagem de email>';

$filters[] = 'SUBJECT "' . addcslashes($assunto, '"\\') . '"';
```

Então após os filtros adicione isto (o `UNSEEN`) será somente para pegar mensagens não lidas ainda:

```
$filters[] = 'UNSEEN';

$uids = imap_search($mbox, implode(' ', $filters), SE_UID);
```

Então o retorno pode ser baixado assim:

```
foreach ($uids as $uid) {

    $header = imap_headerinfo($mbox, $uid);
    $structure = imap_fetchstructure($mbox, $uid);

    //Pega os dados da origem do email
    $fromAddress    = isset($header->from) ? $header->from : null;
    $toAddress      = isset($header->to) ? $header->to : null;
    $ccAddress      = isset($header->cc) ? $header->cc : null;
    $bccAddress     = isset($header->bcc) ? $header->bcc : null;
    $replyToAddress = isset($header->reply_to) ? $header->reply_to : null;
    $subject        = isset($header->subject) ? $header->subject : null;
    $date           = isset($header->date) ? $header->date : null;

    if ($structure->type === 1) {
        $mensagem = imap_fetchbody($mbox, $uid, '2');
    } else {
        $mensagem = imap_body($mbox, $uid);
    }

    // Salvar dados das variáveis no banco aqui

}
```

E para marcar **como lido** use a função `imap_setflag_full`:

```
 imap_setflag_full($mbox, $uid, '\\SEEN', SE_UID)
```

Então basta pegar as variáveis e salvar os dados em um banco de dados ou outro tipo que desejar, um exemplo de inserção no mysql seria algo como:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

/* verifica a conexão */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

$mbox = imap_open('{imap.dominio.com:143/imap/novalidate-cert}INBOX', '<seu email>', '<senha>')
            or die('Erro ao conectar com o Email');

$assunto = 'ASSUNTO TESTE';

$filters[] = 'SUBJECT "' . addcslashes($assunto, '"\\') . '"';

$filters[] = 'UNSEEN';

$uids = imap_search($mbox, implode(' ', $filters), SE_UID);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO mensagens (uid, from, to, cc, bcc, replyto, assunto, data, mensagem) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

if ($stmt) {
    foreach ($uids as $uid) {

        $header = imap_headerinfo($mbox, $uid);
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($mbox, $uid);

        //Pega os dados da origem do email
        $fromAddress    = isset($header->from) ? $header->from : null;
        $toAddress      = isset($header->to) ? $header->to : null;
        $ccAddress      = isset($header->cc) ? $header->cc : null;
        $bccAddress     = isset($header->bcc) ? $header->bcc : null;
        $replyToAddress = isset($header->reply_to) ? $header->reply_to : null;
        $subject        = isset($header->subject) ? $header->subject : null;
        $date           = isset($header->date) ? $header->date : null;

        if ($structure->type === 1) {
            $mensagem = imap_fetchbody($mbox, $uid, '2');
        } else {
            $mensagem = imap_body($mbox, $uid);
        }

        // Salvar dados das variáveis no banco aqui
        $stmt->bind_param('issssssss', $uid, $from, $to, $cc, $bcc, $replyto, $assunto, $data, $mensagem);

        $stmt->execute();

        // Marca como lido
        imap_setflag_full($mbox, $uid, '\\SEEN', SE_UID);
    }

    printf("Foram inseridas %d mensagens.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

    $stmt->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
```